# W/Ads: It is not recommended to show an interstitial when app is not in foreground

Tags: android, background, ads, interstitial, foreground

Do you know this "W/Ads: It is not recommended to show an interstitial when app is not in foreground." 
How can i prevent this Warning/Error , I'm trying to show an interstitial when app is on foreground but the device is lock,under security.
on some device i'm can display interstitial when the device is lock and on other device i'm block.
Any Ideas?

Comment: same issue did you find why on some devices this message is shown?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You try to show an interstitialAd while the Activity is not in foreground.
You have to check if your activity is in foreground. If so, show the ad.

For example implementing a lifecycle listener.
After resume check if ad is loaded and show it.

GGK